# How to auto - hide keyboard when Expandable Table Cell is tapped in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The scenario is the user searches data in `UISearchController` and after it filters the data, the user will tapped the data in an `expandable cell`(For the expandable cell i used `FoldingCell` pod). But when the user taps the  expandable cell, the keyboard is still visible. How can I auto-hide the keyboard when the user taps the expandable cell? I just search possible techniques here in SO but it doesn't work for my app. Any reference or solution you can recommend that i can use?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FoldingCell

    if cell.isAnimating() {
        return
    }

    var duration = 0.0

    if cellHeights[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] == kCloseCellHeight { // open cell
        cellHeights[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] = kOpenCellHeight
        cell.unfold(true, animated: true, completion: nil)
        duration = 0.3
    } else {// close cell
        cellHeights[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] = kCloseCellHeight
        cell.unfold(false, animated: true, completion: nil)
        duration = 0.5
    }


    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()


    }, completion: nil)

     self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

**ConfigureSearchBar**

```
func configureSearchBar() {



    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()


    searchController.searchBar.textColor = UIColor.black
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search by name, department or employee number"
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
    searchController.searchBar.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "search-2"), for: .search, state: .highlighted)
    searchController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)


    searchController.searchBar.isTranslucent = true



    self.ParticipantTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing `resignFirstResponder()` on the `searchBar` property of your **UISearchController**?

Comment: `self.view.endEditing(true)` should help

Comment: In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, end the editing using this `self.view.endEditing(true)`.

Comment: @DV  i tried to insert here but still doesnt work `func configureSearchBar() { searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false definesPresentationContext = true searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: @EhsanSaddique hi, Kindly check the codes above for the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. I added your suggested answer but the keyboard hides only when I scroll up the `tableview` but when I tapped the `expandable cell` the keyboard is not hiding.

Comment: Did you add : `searchController.searchBar.delegate = self`

Comment: @Titus Try moving `self.view.endEditing(true)` to the first line in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` because you have a return statement, it might be reason your keyboard is not dismissing.

Comment: @EhsanSaddique i moved the  `self.view.endEditing(true)` to the first line but still it is not working

Comment: @TungVuDuc Hi, I did not include `searchController.searchBar.delegate = self` in `configureSearchBar` function, which part of my code will I insert it? I included the codes for  `SearchBar` Thank you.

Comment: If you can share me your project, I'd help you better

Comment: @TungVuDuc I am encountering problem in internet connection here in my area. I am having a hard time in uploading my updated repo.